# cannot use offset and limit in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

currently i am using `offset` and `limit` to retrieve limited data from table, but when i move the database from `development` to `hosting server`, it show syntax error on query, if i remove `offset` and `limit` syntax, it will be work well. Any idea or solution on this problem?

```
    SELECT
    e.A,
    e.B,
    e.C,
    e.D,
    e.E,
    e.F,
    e.G
    FROM
    T1 e
    where e.A = 1
    order by e.B desc
    limit in_count
    offset in_offset;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official mysql site :

> For compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL supports the LIMIT row_count
>   OFFSET offset syntax.

I think your syntax is proper, the problem may reside with the procedure variables being used in the `LIMIT/OFFSET` clause, or the way it is being interpreted by the database engine that might have an older incompatible version that could not interpret `OFFSET`.

As an alternative workaround, try using the `,` comma separation in the LIMIT clause to specify the `OFFSET`, this might solve the issue.

```
SELECT
    e.A,
    e.B,
    e.C,
    e.D,
    e.E,
    e.F,
    e.G
    FROM
    T1 e
    where e.A = 1
    order by e.B desc
    limit in_offset,in_count;
```

Comment: (The problem is in substitutions inside a Stored Procedure.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very likely due to your hosting provider using an older version of the MySQL server than you use in test.

The problem you describe is a bug that has been fixed in MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918

The fix was released as of version 5.5.6 in the third calendar quarter of 2010.
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-6.html

If you have a pre-5.5.6 version of MySQL at your hosting provider, this explains your difficulty. Issue the

```
 STATUS
```

command to MySQL to get it to tell you its version among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `in_count` and `in_offset` filled in like that.  (Similarly, you cannot pass in a table name, or a few other constructs.)

Instead, use `CONCAT` to build a string containing the `SELECT` with the `in_count`, etc, filled in.  Then `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, and `DEALLOCATE`.

(Do not use `USING` to try to fill in `in_count`; it will fail for the same reason.  Hence the use of `CONCAT`.)

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,564143,564143
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,565020,566489

For example:

```
SET @s = concat('SELECT * FROM ', uview, ' ORDER BY ', uindex, ' LIMIT ', offset, ',2000' );
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Mysql procedures can apply direct SQL queries without the need of prepared statement where you can pass any form of variables you want which gets substituted as far as it is properly initialized, you can call this as a workaround but not really the main problem @RickJames